# How to isolate a word that corresponds with a letter from a different column of a CSV file?

Tags: perl, bash, sed

I have a CSV file, like this:

```
ACDB,this is a sentence
BECD,this is another sentence
BCAB,this is yet another
```

Each character in the first column corresponds to a word in the second column, e.g., in the first column, `A` corresponds with "this", `C` with "is", `D` with "a", and `B`, with sentence.

Given the variable `character`, which can be set to any of the characters appearing in the first column, I need to isolate the word which corresponds to the selected letter, e.g., if I set `character="B"`, then the output of the above would be:

```
sentence
this
this another
```

If I set `character="C", then the output of the above would be:

```
is
another
is
```

How can I output only those words which correspond to the position of the selected letter?

- The file contains many UTF-8 characters.
- For every character in column 1, there is always an equal number of words in column 2.
- The words in column 2 are separated by spaces.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
while read line
do
    characters="$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')"
    words="$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}')"
    character="B"
done < ./file.csv
```

Comment: Using `awk` for no other reason than to select fields in a shell script isn't the greatest. You're actually performing at least 3 unnecessary forks for each assignment: one for the pipe and unneeded echo (use `here{string,doc}s`), one for the process substitution, one for awk, and possibly another for the subshell awk is run in depending on implementation details. Just use `read` - no further parsing required: `while read -r characters words _; do ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
x=B                                                      # set wanted key variable
sed '
:a;s/^\([^,]\)\(.*,\)\([^ \n]*\) *\(.*\)/\2\4\n\1 \3/;ta # pair keys with values
s/,//                                                    # delete ,
s/\n[^'$x'] [^\n]*//g                                    # delete unwanted keys/values
s/\n.//g                                                 # delete wanted keys
s/ //                                                    # delete first space
/^$/d                                                    # delete empty lines
' file
sentence
this
this another
```

or in awk:

```
awk -F, -vx=B '{i=split($1,a,"");split($2,b," ");c=s="";for(n=1;n<=i;n++)if(a[n]==x){c=c s b[n];s=" "} if(length(c))print c}' file
sentence
this
this another
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mostly - done rump answer.

Since SO is not a "Do my work for me" site, you will need to fill in some trivial blanks.

```
sub get_index_of_char {
   my ($character, $charset) = @_;
   # Homework: read about index() function
   #http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html
}

sub split_line {
    my ($line) = @_;
    # Separate the line into a charset (before comma), 
    # and whitespace separated word list.
    # You can use a regex for that
    my ($charset, @words) = ($line =~ /^([^,]+),(?(\S+)\s+)+(\S+)$/g); # Not tested
    return ($charset, \@words);
}

sub process_line {
    my ($line, $character) = @_;
    chomp($line);
    my ($charset, $words) = split_line($line);
    my $index = get_index_of_char($character, $charset);
    print $words->[$index] . "\n"; # Could contain a off-by-one bug
}

# Here be the main loop calling process_line() for every line from input
```

Comment: BTW, for real production, splitting the line on a comma with a regex is not usually a good idea. Use Text::CSV_XS or other CPAN CSV module

Comment: A capture within a repeat like `/(?:(\S+)\s+)+/` will return only the *last* captured value. You need a global match to return them all.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick. It reads data from within the source file using the DATA file handle, whereas you will have to obtain it from your own source. You may also have to cater for there being no word corresponding to a given letter (as for 'A' in the second data line here).

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;

while (<DATA>) {
  my ($keys, $words) = split /,/;
  my @keys = split //, $keys;
  my @words = split ' ', $words;
  my %index;
  push @{ $index{shift @keys} }, shift @words while @keys;
  push @data, \%index;
}

for my $character (qw/ B C /) {
  print "character = $character\n";
  print join(' ', @{$_->{$character}}), "\n" for @data;
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
ACDB,this is a sentence
BECD,this is another sentence
BCAB,this is yet another
```

**output**

```perl
character = B
sentence
this
this another

character = C
is
another
is
```